# When launching applications on iOS, the application interface has shrunk

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, auto-route

There is no such problem on Android, I use auto_route for navigation, respectively, indents and similar widgets are not used anywhere higher up the widget tree, for the bottom panel of AutoTabsRouter, what could be the reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Xd1.jpg)

Below is the main block of code where AutoTabsRouter is used:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsRouter(
      routes: const [
        HomeRoute(),
        BranchesRoute(),
        QrCodeRoute(),
        NewsRoute(),
        ProfileRoute(),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          body: child,
          bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
                onTap: (index) => _openPage(context, index, tabsRouter),
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.main.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.iconJiraffe),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.branches.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.branches),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.news.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.news),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.profile.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.user),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.maybePaddingOf(context)?.bottom ?? 0,
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: ThemeHelper.gray13,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 6,
                      horizontal: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(IconHelper.viewfinder),
                  onPressed: () => _showModalBottomSheet(context),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Below is the code of the news screen itself, built on the Scaffold widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsRouter(
      routes: const [
        HomeRoute(),
        BranchesRoute(),
        QrCodeRoute(),
        NewsRoute(),
        ProfileRoute(),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          body: child,
          bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
                onTap: (index) => _openPage(context, index, tabsRouter),
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.main.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.iconJiraffe),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.branches.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.branches),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.news.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.news),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: LocaleKeys.profile.tr(),
                    icon: const ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage(IconHelper.user),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.maybePaddingOf(context)?.bottom ?? 0,
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: ThemeHelper.gray13,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 6,
                      horizontal: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(IconHelper.viewfinder),
                  onPressed: () => _showModalBottomSheet(context),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: A title should summarize your question, please don't use it as the first sentence of your question. In addition, please use formatting like headers sparingly, it only distracts from the message (I have edited your question to fix this, but you may want to review your question and include more details).

Comment: Understood, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).